# Adding custom data to cucumber report

Tags: cucumberjs

For my cucumberjs tests, I have a need to add some custom information to my cucumber report.  I tried using the `World` object like this in the `After` hook:

```
this.sampleData = 'My Sample Data'
```

Does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled using Nodejs Buffer object like below:

let userDetails = {
  username: "test",
  password: "test"
}

const userDetails = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(userDetails));
await this.World.attach(userDetails, 'application/json');

This will attach your test data as JSON object at the end of scenario in your cucumber BDD report